# Is there a easy way to support dynamic number of sections with DiffUtil.Callback

Tags: java, android

We are using this thin wrapper to implement Section in `RecyclerView` - https://github.com/luizgrp/SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter

Currently, we have 3 sections in `RecyclerView`

1. Note
2. Archive
3. Trash

[image].

However, to achieve the above outcome, I need to provide a `DiffUtil.Callback` implementation, with fixed number of Sections.

```
public class SearchedNoteDiffUtilCallback extends DiffUtil.Callback {
    private static final int TYPE_ARCHIVED_HEADER = 1;
    private static final int TYPE_TRASHED_HEADER = 2;
    private static final int TYPE_NOTES_EMPTY = 3;
    private static final int TYPE_ARCHIVED_EMPTY = 4;
    private static final int TYPE_TRASHED_EMPTY = 5;
    private static final int TYPE_NOTES_LOADING = 6;
    private static final int TYPE_ARCHIVED_LOADING = 7;
    private static final int TYPE_TRASHED_LOADING = 8;
    private static final int TYPE_CONTENT = 9;

    private final List<Note> newNotes;
    private final List<Note> oldNotes;

    private final List<Note> newArchivedNotes;
    private final List<Note> oldArchivedNotes;

    private final List<Note> newTrashedNotes;
    private final List<Note> oldTrashedNotes;

    private final boolean newArchivedNoteHasHeader;
    private final boolean oldArchivedNoteHasHeader;

    private final boolean newTrashedNoteHasHeader;
    private final boolean oldTrashedNoteHasHeader;

    private final Section.State newNotesState;
    private final Section.State oldNotesState;
    
    private final Section.State newArchivedState;
    private final Section.State oldArchivedState;
    
    private final Section.State newTrashedState;
    private final Section.State oldTrashedState;

    private final String newSearchedKeyword;
    private final String oldSearchedKeyword;

    public SearchedNoteDiffUtilCallback(
            List<Note> newNotes,
            List<Note> oldNotes,
            List<Note> newArchivedNotes,
            List<Note> oldArchivedNotes,
            List<Note> newTrashedNotes,
            List<Note> oldTrashedNotes,
            boolean newArchivedNoteHasHeader,
            boolean oldArchivedNoteHasHeader,
            boolean newTrashedNoteHasHeader,
            boolean oldTrashedNoteHasHeader,
            Section.State newNotesState,
            Section.State oldNotesState,
            Section.State newArchivedState,
            Section.State oldArchivedState,
            Section.State newTrashedState,
            Section.State oldTrashedState,
            String newSearchedKeyword,
            String oldSearchedKeyword
    ) {

        this.newNotes = newNotes;
        this.oldNotes = oldNotes;

        this.newArchivedNotes = newArchivedNotes;
        this.oldArchivedNotes = oldArchivedNotes;

        this.newTrashedNotes = newTrashedNotes;
        this.oldTrashedNotes = oldTrashedNotes;

        this.newArchivedNoteHasHeader = newArchivedNoteHasHeader;
        this.oldArchivedNoteHasHeader = oldArchivedNoteHasHeader;

        this.newTrashedNoteHasHeader = newTrashedNoteHasHeader;
        this.oldTrashedNoteHasHeader = oldTrashedNoteHasHeader;

        this.newNotesState = newNotesState;
        this.oldNotesState = oldNotesState;

        this.newArchivedState = newArchivedState;
        this.oldArchivedState = oldArchivedState;

        this.newTrashedState = newTrashedState;
        this.oldTrashedState = oldTrashedState;

        this.newSearchedKeyword = newSearchedKeyword;
        this.oldSearchedKeyword = oldSearchedKeyword;

        if (this.newArchivedNoteHasHeader == newArchivedNotes.isEmpty()) {
            throw new java.lang.IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        if (this.newTrashedNoteHasHeader == newTrashedNotes.isEmpty()) {
            throw new java.lang.IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        if (this.oldArchivedNoteHasHeader == oldArchivedNotes.isEmpty()) {
            throw new java.lang.IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        if (this.oldTrashedNoteHasHeader == oldTrashedNotes.isEmpty()) {
            throw new java.lang.IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        if (newArchivedNoteHasHeader && newArchivedState != Section.State.LOADED) {
            throw new java.lang.IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        if (newTrashedNoteHasHeader && newTrashedState != Section.State.LOADED) {
            throw new java.lang.IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        if (oldArchivedNoteHasHeader && oldArchivedState != Section.State.LOADED) {
            throw new java.lang.IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        if (oldTrashedNoteHasHeader && oldTrashedState != Section.State.LOADED) {
            throw new java.lang.IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        Assert(this.newNotesState == Section.State.LOADED || this.newNotesState == Section.State.EMPTY || this.newNotesState == Section.State.LOADING);
        Assert(this.oldNotesState == Section.State.LOADED || this.oldNotesState == Section.State.EMPTY || this.oldNotesState == Section.State.LOADING);
        Assert(this.newArchivedState == Section.State.LOADED);
        Assert(this.oldArchivedState == Section.State.LOADED);
        Assert(this.newTrashedState == Section.State.LOADED);
        Assert(this.oldTrashedState == Section.State.LOADED);
    }

    
      //
      // Provide proper implementation. Complex implementations required.
      //
      /*
      public abstract int getOldListSize();
      public abstract int getNewListSize();
      public abstract boolean areItemsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition);
      public abstract boolean areContentsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition);
      */
```

---

But, how about situations when we have dynamic number of Sections? Is there any easier way, to support dynamic number of sections with `DiffUtil.Callback`?

Comment: If you can cope with alpha releases, each section could be handled by a separate `ConcatAdapter`. See https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/merge-adapters-sequentially-with-mergeadapter-294d2942127a for more. Hopefully, this will ship in final form before the end of 2020.